# Quick Question: Can I make only a section of my site used by Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I don't want my whole site to be run on wordpress. Only the blog portion, perhaps. Is there a quick and painless way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

1. Install WordPress into a
   subdirectory of your web site. 
   http://example.com/blog
2. Install
   WordPress onto a subdomain of your
   main domain. 
   http://blog.example.com

Comment: So when I download wordpress, I put everything in the wordpress site in my /blog folder (instead of my root) and start from there?

Comment: Exactly.  That's all it takes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course... the Wordpress documentation is a good place to start!
http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress